# Обработка форм с помощью python

Tags: веб-программирование, python-3.x, form, httpbackend

Есть html страница. На странице:

```
<form>
   <input type='text'>
</form>
```

Также есть python скрипт, считающий количество символов в запросе. 
Вопрос: Как скриптом обработать запрос из формы и ответ скрипта вывести в окно браузера?

Comment: На Питоне существует множество библиотек для работы с web. Какую именно библиотеку использует ваш  *"python скрипт, считающий количество символов в запросе"*?

Comment: Никакую. Просто используется: input() - получаем запрос и метод len() - считаем кол-во. С тем, какой будет обработка запроса - вроде все понятно. Не понятно как запрос передать в обрабатывающий скрипт, и после вернуть его обратно в браузер.
А так, если я правильно понял вопрос, в дальнейшем обработкой ответа на запрос будет заниматься BeautifulSoup.

Comment: *"не понятно как запрос передать в обрабатывающий скрипт"* Кто вам сказал, что вы можете запрос прочитать с помощью `input()`? (это возможно, но это не единственный и не самый предпочтительный способ). Если вы думаете, что сервер может вероятно использовать BeautifulSoup для обработки запроса из HTML формы, то у вас отсутствует адекватная модель об этом процессе. Легко ответить на ваш вопрос кодом, используя одну из десятков web framework—какую выбрать может зависеть от конкретной задачи. Если забыть как это реализовано, какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Нормально мы так все запутались :)
1) Я не читаю запрос input()-ом, я input()-ом, в качестве примера, передаю запрос. Как если бы этот запрос пришёл не из input(), а из той самой формы.

Comment: Прошлый комментарий криво отправился, извиняюсь.

В общем, изначально суть была такой: есть форма, в форму пользователь вводит запрос, нажимает на кнопку отправить и его перекидывает на страницу на которой ему в браузере отображается кол-во символов (сколько букв, знаков) в его запросе.

Comment: В такой постановке, вообще запрос можно в JavaScript обработать прямо на клиенте. Чтобы на пустяках не спотыкаться, попробуйте по основам веб-разработки книжку почитать, чтобы немного ориентироваться. Иначе несколько строк, которые реализуют обработку http post запроса вам не помогут.  Если не знаете какую книгу выбрать, то спросите (такие вопросы особый статус имеют, так как могут спам привлекать и чересчур субъективны).

Comment: В таком случае - да, мне нужна литература про веб разработку.  Только, с учётом того что я хочу писать на python, мне литературу смотреть лучше в целом по бэкэнду или в рамках python?

Comment: Посмотрите на ["hello world" пример](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Это полный пример кода. Только если вы не знаете слов http, GET POST, url, dns, имя хоста, tcp/ip, порт, content-type, firewall, клиент/сервер—самые самые основы (для сравнения,  только rfc несколько тысяч существует), то развернуть сервис и изменения сложно будет вносить. От Питона можно слово wsgi выучить, всё остальное независимо от Питона  можно посмотреть. Для начала достаточно обзор почитать, чтобы не заблудится.